# Selenium: How to make geckodriver headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have completed code for geckodriver and was wondering how to make geckodriver headless now. I saw a post previously with the following text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, 
executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
driver.quit()
```

I don't understand where the download for options came from under webdriver. When I downloaded geckodriver, all that came with it was the executable file. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 5):

Works for me. Steps I used: (1) Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing geckodriver.exe. (2) Start `geckodriver.exe` without any options from a command prompt. (3) Open another command prompt and type `python` and press the Return key. (4) Copy/paste the following code into your your python session.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
# Don't put the path to geckodriver in the following. But the firefox executable
# must be in the path. If not, include the path to firefox, not geckodriver below.
driver = Firefox(firefox_options=options)

print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
driver.get('http://google.com/')

# Print the first 300 characters on the page.
print(driver.page_source[:300])
driver.quit()
```